# Windows are stuck stretching

Tags: ubuntu, visual-effects

I just updated to the new Ubuntu version.  I have the different things I'm working on each in a different workspace.  Sometimes, when I switch windows (using the new floaty bar on the left), my windows start stretching and get stuck in it.  I can still edit some and click buttons but it makes it very aggravating!  Here is a picture:
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest asking this also on askubuntu.com.

Comment: I would install the compiz manager and adjust the wobble parameters for your windows. I may have the exact names wrong - but you can tune tons and tons of things with Compiz.

Comment: I believe this is by design. :P